# Extend the Command Line Interface with NuGet Sitecore CLI

Tags: sitecore-cli

In Sitecore 10.2, I want to extend the command-line interface with NuGet as mentioned in this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/extend-the-command-line-interface-with-nuget.html) and I want to create a custom `plugin`

I just want to create a simple plugin similar to `dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization`  like `Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.HelloWorld`